# How to use IPython and pyreadline in IronPython?

Tags: .net, python, ironpython, ipython

IPython is a very useful Python Shell, I want to use it in IronPython.
Is it possible?

Comment: IPython is written in Python, so IronPython should be able to run the package as well.

Answer (score 0):

Direct answer from the [IPython FAQ](http://ipython.org/faq.html#can-ipython-run-under-ironpython-pypy-jython-other-python-interpreters) :

> The terminal-based shell should run on any interpreter which complies
>   with the necessary version of Python. IPython 0.11 requires Python 2.6
>   or above, and as of June 2011, IronPython and PyPy both support this.
>
> The most likely problems would come from Readline and from using the
>   undocumented sys._getframe() function. On Windows we ship our own
>   [pyreadline](http://ipython.org/pyreadline.html), which might also work under IronPython. PyPy ships its own
>   readline module, which IPython 0.11 doesn’t use properly; this is
>   fixed in trunk.
>
> If IPython does not work under a supported interpreter, please file a
>   bug.

Answer (score 0):

I successfully made IPython 1.2 work with IronPython 2.7.4 by following the instructions in IPython's wiki page
at https://github.com/ipython/ipython/wiki/Frequently-asked-questions#id9